# With a WCF P2P application can I send into the P2P network without being a node

Tags: .net, wcf, p2p, net.p2p

I have a service with multiple nodes running using WCF P2P.  All of the nodes both send and receive the data that is being passed around.

I have a new node that I would like to have send data into the P2P network of services but it doesn't actually need to receive any data.  Does anyone know if I still have to include it as both a sender and receiver?  Basically, can it send into the P2P network without actually being a node of the network, or is it going to cause issues if I don't implement the Service side of the contract?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will still act as a full node as far as the mesh is concerned (by relaying messages along to other peers) but it will not cause a problem if you don't implement the service side of the contract.